# How Do I Access Windows Shares From BASH?

Tags: networking, command-line, bash, vmware

Probably total noob question. I installed Ubuntu in a VMWare Player. Works fine. I usually work in terminal and didn't realise until today that I could use the Files icon to connect to my Windows host machine (and indeed my office network.) Fabulous!

But... then... how do I access these new shares from inside bash? From my default prompt, shouldn't I see some \my-windows-share

OR do I need to mount these drives somehow 'manually' inside terminal? If so, how?

I see a number of answers regarding VirtualBox. Don't know if that applies to me. I guess I assumed that once I was connected via Files I would automatically be connected with Terminal.

Comment: Check this document https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you need to have samba and cifs-utils installed:

```
sudo apt-get install samba cifs-utils
```

Then use a Bash script to mount windows share folder in linux using samba:

```
$ mkdir /mnt/smb

$ touch smb.sh

chmod +x smb.sh

$ vi smb.sh
```

Write the following into the smb.sh file using vi:

```
#/bin/bash



SERVER_IP="192.168.1.1"

SHARE_NAME="c$"

USERNAME="samba user name"

PASSWD="samba password"

DOMAIN="domain"


mount.cifs //$SERVER_IP/$SHARE_NAME /mnt/smb/ -o username=$USERNAME,password=$PASSWD,dom=$DOMAIN
```

Finally run the script to mount your Windows share and cd into the share:

```
./smb.sh

$ cd /mnt/smb/
```

---

Another method that seems to me to be more straight forward and easier: It involves creating the mount point, editing fstab, and then mounting all filesystems in fstab with one command.

Make the folder:
    sudo mkdir /mnt/myDirectory

Edit the fstab:
    sudo vi /etc/fstab

Append the following to the fstab file:

```
//server/Share /mnt/myDirectory cifs domain=myDomain,username=myUserName,password=myPassword 0 0
```

Be sure to fill in all the appropriate information in place of those placeholders. And save the fstab file with `wq` for "write and quit."

Finally mount all the file systems listed in fstab:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Now you can verify that the share is available with:

```
ls /mnt/myDirectory
```

And you should see the files in the top level directory of the Windows Share.

Comment: 1. For future use, do I really need to use the IP address? I thought I could use the Win share name for some reason? 2. When I tried your method I got an error referring to /etc/fstab. I assume I have to add a line in that file with permissions? If so how do I do -that-?

Comment: 2. I found the /run/user/1000/gvfs folder which contains appears to contain subdirs pointing to the Windows shares. I guess I could  use these. Still want to know how to do this via mount.

Comment: I found an example here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-remote-windows-partition-windows-share-under-linux.html

that says you can use the server name instead of the ip address like so:

# mount -t cifs //ntserver/download -o username=vivek,password=myPassword /mnt/ntserver

Comment: To avoid `Unable to determine destination address.` (dmesg | tail) you need to `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`

Comment: to avoid your password in plain sight use: -o credentials option (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently#Mount_password_protected_network_folders)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is an old article, but still very relevant. I found since the WannaCry ransomware (May 2017) issue many Windows shares refuse to use the old SMB V1.

This is what I ended up having to do
I had the following installed:

```
sudo apt install samba-common samba-common-bin cifs-utils
```

Then add lines under [global] - vi /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
server min protocol = SMB2_10
client min protocol = SMB2
client max protocol = SMB3
```

this then allowed the following command:

```
mount -t cifs -o vers=2.1 -o username=<username>,sec=ntlmssp //server/path /mnt/smb
```